# Can I cast Elemental Touch and Shocking Grasp?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, touch-attacks

Can I cast [Elemental Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-touch) in one round, and then cast [Shocking Grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp) afterwards?
Do they stack? If so, could I cast elemental touch and choose lightning for even more lightning damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, to both of your questions.

I can see why you'd be confused, since typically you can't hold the charge on a spell if you cast another spell. However, *elemental touch* isn't actually a touch spell.  It's a personal spell that targets you.  By casting *elemental touch*, you are giving yourself the ability to make a special melee touch attack for the next few rounds.  If you cast *shocking grasp* afterwards, then you can make your *elemental touch* attack and have it discharge your *shocking grasp* as well.  In addition, there's no reason that you wouldn't be able to use lightning for both.  There are no rules about damage of the same type from multiple sources not stacking.

Be careful, though, that you cast *elemental touch* first.  If you cast *shocking grasp* first, then casting *elemental touch* will discharge your *shocking grasp* to no effect, since casting a spell while you hold the charge discharges your touch spell.

Comment: One thing that wasn't very clear for me. When I cast elemental touch I have X rounds to use just ONE attack, right? Or do I get one every turn?

Comment: You get an attack with the bonus damage every turn.  However, the secondary effects don't stack.  For example, if you hit someone with the acid touch two rounds in a row, they only take 1 point of acid damage each round, not 2.

Comment: Though it wouldn't be a bad idea to ask that as it's own question.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, you can't benefit from two different touch attack spells at the same time, because:

(Taken from FAQ for the [Magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Range), see under Range: Touch, FAQ on the right):

> **If a spell allows multiple touches, are you considered to be holding the charge until all charges are expended?**
>
> Yes.

And from the [combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Spells-in-Combat):

> Holding the Charge: If you don't discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell, you can hold the charge indefinitely. You can continue to make touch attacks round after round. If you touch anything or anyone while holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges. **If you cast another spell, the touch spell dissipates**.

(Emphasis mine)

### However

Since Elemental Touch is **not** a touch spell - it is a spell with range:*personal* which grants a single attack an additional energy damage, and it lasts for 1 round per level. Seems like there's no problem with casting Elemental Touch, and a round later casting Shocking Grasp. As long as you hit before the Elemental Touch ends, you apply the damage from both spells to the attack.